# Swift: flatmap still returning optional

Tags: swift

I'm trying to match the objects in my AnyObject array to a particular string and I've gone down the path of flatmap to return a non-optional array but still getting optional back.

```
typealias PropertyList = [AnyObject]

var savedProgram: PropertyList?
var savedProgramUnwrapped = savedProgram.flatMap{ $0 }

savedProgram
savedProgramUnwrapped
print(savedProgramUnwrapped)
print(savedProgram)
```

Why do savedProgram and savedProgramUnwrapped still look the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap` can remove optional values from an array. You have an optional array, not an array of optionals. This works fine:

```
let arrayOfOptionals: [Int?] = [1, nil, 5, 2, nil]
let arrayOfNumbers = arrayOfOptionals.flatMap { $0 }
print(arrayOfNumbers) // [1, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `flatMap` method do nothing in your case. This method have effect on `Element` of array, but your elements anyway non-optional